# Memory issues while parsing json file in ijson

Tags: python, json

This tutorial https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-json-tutorial/   has a 600MB file that they work with, however when I run their code

```
import ijson

filename = "md_traffic.json"
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    objects = ijson.items(f, 'meta.view.columns.item')
    columns = list(objects)
```

I'm running into 10+ minutes of waiting for the file to be read into ijson and I'm really confused how this is supposed to be reasonable. Shouldn't there be parsing? Am I missing something?

Comment: If I got it well, you use list() to iterate over an iterator whose purpose is to avoid such operation ?

The example given in the tuto is misleading. It should not be use on the whole file but only on a part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a direct copy/paste of the tutorial found here:

https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-json-tutorial/

The reason it's taking so long is the `list()` around the output of the `ijson.items` function.  This effectively forces parsing of the *entire* file before returning any results.  Taking advantage of the `ijson.items` being a generator, the first result can be returned almost immediately:

```
import ijson

filename = "md_traffic.json"
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for item in ijson.items(f, 'meta.view.columns.item'):
        print(item)
        break
```

**EDIT**: The very next step in the tutorial is `print(columns[0])`, which is why I included printing the first item in the answer.  Also, it's not clear whether the question was for Python 2 or 3, so the answer uses syntax that works in both, albeit inelegantly.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is not that you are creating a `list` after parsing (that only collects the individual results into a single structure), but that you are using the default pure-python backend provided by ijson.

There are other backends that can be used which are way faster. In [ijson's homepage](https://github.com/isagalaev/ijson) it is explained how you can import those. The `yajl2_cffi` backend is the fastest currently available at the moment, but I've created a new `yajl2_c` backend (there's a [pull request](https://github.com/isagalaev/ijson/pull/58) pending acceptance) that performs even better.

In my laptop (Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5600U) using the `yajl2_cffi` backend your code runs in ~1.5 minutes. Using the `yajl2_c` backend it runs in ~10.5 seconds (python 3) and ~15 seconds (python 2.7.12).

Edit: @lex-scarisbrick is of course also right in that you can quickly break out of the loop if you are only interested in the column names.

Answer (score 1):

I tried running your code and I killed the program after 25 minutes. So yes 10 minutes it's reasonable fast.

Comment: I didn't explicitly note that after 10+ minutes I killed it too ;)